# Playbook getting stuck when non-OS Python Interpreter is enforced on managed node

Tags: python, ansible

I am trying to automate the deployment for one of the applications which is hosted RHEL 5.6. OS comes with Python 2.4.3 as default.
My Ansible Control Node is running with 2.7.5 on RHEL 7.2 with Python 2.7.5.

I have installed Python 2.7.5 is a different location on managed node and forced Ansible to use the new one but now it gets stuck with no output getting produced.

When I tried to run playbook, it failed with the error:

```
fatal: [<hostname>]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/secure/ShellScript/Params/SFT_Folder.txt): Shared connection to <IP Address> closed.\r\n"
```

A verbose output suggested the issue of using /usr/bin/python

I installed Python 2.7.5 in a different location on managed node and added ansible_python_interpreter=/opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7 in hosts file

This changed the verbose error to shared library while keeping the final error message same:

```
<IP Address> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=batchusr -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ce68d6977c -tt <IP Address> '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7 /home/batchusr/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1554464098.34-28789780698815/AnsiballZ_stat.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<10.30.18.6> (127, '/opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\r\n', 'Shared connection to <IP Address> closed.\r\n')
fatal: [ibmsitlsft02]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/secure/ShellScript/Params/SFT_Folder.txt): Shared connection to <IP Address> closed.\r\n"
```

So, I created an executable python file with below contents, changed the interpreter location and gave it another go

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/python2.7/lib
/opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7
```

Now it is just getting stuck at the below step and no further output or log is produced.

```
<IP Address> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=batchusr -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/home/ansible/.ansible/cp/ce68d6977c -tt <IP Address> '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/opt/python2.7/python /home/batchusr/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1554464252.78-244901400191906/AnsiballZ_stat.py && sleep 0'"'"''

ansible-playbook -i inventories/hosts sft_deploy_main.yml -vvv
```

Expected output:

```
PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************
<hostname>                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Actual Output:
Not moving forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most recent issue is caused by the wrapper you've written.

You've attempted to replace the python executable with this:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/python2.7/lib
/opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7
```

There are two problems with this:

1. You really should start this with `#!/bin/sh` rather than relying on the fallback behavior.
2. You should use `exec /opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7` rather than keeping a shell process hanging around, and
3. Most significantly, you are discarding all the arguments to the `python` command.  You need to change:

   ```
   /opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7
   ```

   To:

   ```
   /opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7 "$@"
   ```

As you have written your wrapper, when you run:

```
/path/to/wrapper myfile.py
```

You will in fact start up an interactive Python interpreter rather than running `myfile.py`, which is why your playbook run is hanging.

Taking a step back, a better solution than using a wrapper would be to configure `/etc/ld.so.conf` appropriately so that `/opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7` can run without setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Thank you larsks for the options. The change in /etc/ld.so.conf didn't help, however, I have added the argument change along with other two improvements you have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your executable file is not accepting the arguments passed to it. What if you try replacing your executable file with:

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/python2.7/lib
/opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7 "$@"
```

Also make sure that the execute bit is set on that file.

Comment: Thank you @MassPikeMike

Comment: You are welcome. Please consider upvoting any of the answers that were useful to you (by clicking the upward pointing triangle above its current vote count of zero) and accepting the best one by checking it.

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion from larsks and MassPikeMike, I have now amended python file on the managed node to below and it works perfectly now:

```
# cat /opt/python2.7/python
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/python2.7/lib
exec /opt/python2.7/bin/python2.7 "$@"
```

Comment: This looks pretty much like what I suggested.  If my answer helped you out, you should accept it by checking the checkmark to the left of my answer.

Comment: Hi larsks, I am new to this platform, so wasn't aware of answer marking option. I have accepted the answer now. Thank you very much again for your help.